# IIS 405.. server.tas file

Tags: java, http, iis, http-status-code-405

I am currently trying to integrate a java applet with an ASP.NET site i am building..

The applet is built on the thinkmap SDK framework..

The applet starts successfully however it throws an error about the data configuration file..

```
Fatal Error: A fatal error occurred when fetching metadata :  : Remote Error: HTTP Error: 405 Server responded with:HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed for URL: server.tas Check the server logs or the Thinkmap Application Server status servlet (tas_status) for more details.
```

The company who developed the frameworks support say its not their responsibility to help me set this up on IIS and wont help..

Is there a setting in IIS i need to tweak to allow this file to be accessible or mapped to an extension or anything like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you you have the problem with Request sent from applet to IIS web service. In order to troubleshot it I recommend you first of all to install [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and trace request/response.

Then you will see the exact request. You can post it here or google it and see why such requests are blocked by IIS.

By the way, if are trying to download .tas file it's unknown file extention and it will be blocked by IIS what you can do is to [add MIME format in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx). it might help.

Hope it helps. 
Danny.